# Minishift hangs on startup

Tags: minishift

I'm trying to run minishift in a Centos 7 VM running in Oracle VirtualBox on a Windows 7 PC. When I issue the "minishift start" command , the session hangs at "Starting VM minshift". I've tried starting minishift with the debug flag "--show-libmachine-logs -v 5" , but with no results.

The environment is a Windows 7 PC with an I3-4160 processor and 16G memory, with 11G and two threads allocated to the VM. Minishift is using the KVM drivers.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions, or are there any other debug flags I can specify?

Thanks,

Graeme

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to re-install it. I currently have the same CPU and it might be a possibility that your CPU is not in the recommended system specifications. But that might be a possibility.